# Why is this click event firing for the wrong element?"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a zoom out function. When I click anywhere on screen, it does zoom out, but immediately after, it zooms back in. Why is it like that, even though I have used an **if** function?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html onclick="zoomOut()"> <!--zoom out added to html element-->
    <head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <style>

    .pic{
        height:150px;
    }
    .picbig{
        position: absolute;
        width:0px;
        -webkit-transition:width 0.3s linear 0s;
        transition:width 0.3s linear 0s;
        z-index:10;
    }

    .picb
    {

        width:500px;
    }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body >

    <div id="edgetoedge">
    <img id="1" class="pic" src="numerouno.jpg"  onClick="zoom(this.id)">
    <img class="picbig" src="numerouno.jpg"  >

    <img id="2" class="pic" src="numerodue.jpg" alt="heart" onClick="zoom(this.id)">
    <img  class="picbig" src="numerodue.jpg" >

    <img id="3" class="pic" src="numerotre.jpg" alt="hardhat" onClick="zoom(this.id)">
    <img class="picbig" src="numerotre.jpg" >
    </div>

    <script>

    var x=1;

    function zoom(clicked_id)
    {
        $("#"+clicked_id).next().toggleClass("picb");
    }
```

This is zoomOut function

```
function zoomOut()
    {alert("zooming out"); if ($("#edgetoedge img").hasClass( "picb" )) {$(".picbig").removeClass("picb");}}
```

rest of the code don't matter

Comment: Good work figuring out your own question! Minor criticism; usually, you'll want to name your question with its most generic application. For instance, "Why is this click event firing for the wrong element?" This helps both people with the same issue, and ensures the most relevant people notice your question.

Comment: Fixed  question. But the problem was that i didn't really know that event bubbling was the issue, hens the strange question :/

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding event.stopPropagation(); to zoom function

```
function zoom(clicked_id)
    {


            $("#"+clicked_id).next().toggleClass("picb");
        event.stopPropagation();



    }
```